# What is the Java equivalent to this preg_replace?

Tags: java, php, regex, replaceall

```
<?php
    $str = "word <a href=\"word\">word</word>word word";
    $str = preg_replace("/word(?!([^<]+)?>)/i","repl",$str);
    echo $str;
    # repl <word word="word">repl</word>
?>
```

source: http://pureform.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/matching-a-word-characters-outside-of-html-tags/

Unfortunality my project needs a semantic libs avaliable only for Java...

// Thanks Celso

Comment: You seriously need to rephrase this question.  1) what does this have to do with java?  2) what is your expected input and output?

Comment: result expected:

repl <a href="word">repl</word>repl repl

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the String.replaceAll() method:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "word <a href=\"word\">word</word>word word";
    str = str.replaceAll("word(?!([^<]+)?>)", "repl");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

To translate that regex for use in Java, all you have to do is get rid of the `/` delimiters and change the trailing `i` to an inline modifier, `(?i)`.  But it's not a very good regex; I would use this instead:

```
(?i)word(?![^<>]++>)
```

According to RegexBuddy's Debug feature, when it tries to match the `word` in `<a href="word">`, the original regex requires 23 steps to reject it, while this one takes only seven steps.  The actual Java code is

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)word(?![^<>]++>)", "repl");
```

Comment: Thanks Alan for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Before providing a further answer, are you trying to parse an html document? If so, don't use regexes, use an html parser.

Comment: my tool "generates" XHTML replacing terms in a txt in a new tags using the terms as a value inside of tag, i am using the replaceAll approach because some terms can be composited like "Celso Araujo Fontes". 

Example, how replaceAll myTerm in this situation

myTerm is <friends='z myTerm w'> cool friend </friend>