# Remove comments and write to new text file without comments

Tags: comments

i need to make a program where the input file is a source code with comments and output is the same code without comments.

It would be perfect if it would eliminate the /* */ comments also.

Comment: Which language? What have you tried?.. etc

Comment: i was wondering if there is an example anywhere, id prefer java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to solve your problem you'll have to user preg_replace

```
    $notCommentedFile = preg_replace('/#.*/', '', $commentedFile);
    $notCommentedFile = preg_replace('#//.*#', '', $notCommentedFile);
    $notCommentedFile = preg_replace('#/\*(?:[^*]*(?:\*(?!/))*)*\*/#', '', $notCommentedFile);
```

this 3 pattern will remove the comment on your file ^^

UPDATE

ups! didn't see the comment X/ this works for php, but i think a java function like preg_replace exist and regular expression are universal :D

here an example on how to use the equivalent preg_replace in java
[What is the Java equivalent to this preg_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304925/how-the-java-equivalent-to-this-preg-replace)

Comment: i can understand a -1 but at least provide a reason for that.